# Parse Security: able to see request/response in plain-text via proxy server

Tags: parse-platform

I'm attempting to hack the Parse SDK, and it seems that we are able to see requests and responses in plain text via a proxy server between Parse and the app. I assumed the data was encrypted, but a malicious user is able to see our requests and modify them to essentially pull out all of our user information.

Does anyone have any ideas on this?

Here is an example of a custom request and response via Proxy:

```
POST /1/classes/_User HTTP/1.1
Host: api.parse.com
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8
Cookie: _parse_session=---
Accept: */*
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
X-Parse-Application-Id: ---
X-Parse-Client-Key: ---
X-Parse-Installation-Id: ---
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
X-Parse-OS-Version: 8.2 (12D508)
Accept-Language: en-us
X-Parse-Client-Version: i1.6.5
Content-Length: 51
Connection: keep-alive
X-Parse-App-Build-Version: 11
X-Parse-App-Display-Version: 1.0.0

{"where":{"email":"joe@joe.com"},"_method":"GET"}

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 10 Apr 2015 01:02:55 GMT
Server: nginx/1.6.0
X-Parse-Platform: G1
X-Runtime: 0.013113
Content-Length: 246
Connection: keep-alive

{"results":[{"company":"","createdAt":"2015-04-10T01:02:35.670Z","discoverable":true,"email":"joe@joe.com","firstName":"Joe","lastName":"Smith","objectId":"yPTx1kyHei","title":"","updatedAt":"2015-04-10T01:02:35.670Z","username":"joe@joe.com"}]}
```

Comment: You should be getting certificate errors

Comment: added an example of what i see @SLaks

Comment: Is the request happening over HTTPS? Does your proxy install a trusted certificate?